# How to show invisible characters in <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a text area in my HTML page where I need to show the invisible characters along with the text. The invisible characters can include non-breaking hyphen, non-breaking space, trailing space, line break. This should also exposed RTL markers such as: U+202B Right-to-left embedding and U+202C Pop Directional Formatting.

How can I achieve this using HTML / JS / CSS ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/HTML display hidden characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432810/php-html-display-hidden-characters)

Comment: exactly how do you want the invisible characters to be seen? should a line break show up as /n? or unicode?

Comment: Line break should be shown as unicode. Also, I need to show the RTL markers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a editor lib like [tinymce](https://tiny.cloud) or [ace](https://ace.c9.io/) which has a feature for displaying invisible characters.