# str_replace not working even though search parameters look identical to portion of subject

Tags: php, magento

I have this simple bit of code:

```
var_dump($currentUrl);
var_dump($baseUrl);
// strip out base url, so we just get slug of page
$currentSlug = str_replace($baseUrl,'',$currentUrl);
var_dump($currentSlug);
```

This is outputting:

```
string(50) "http://mysite.lcl/books/our-series/boffin-boy.html"
string(27) "http://mysite.lcl/"
string(50) "http://mysite.lcl/books/our-series/boffin-boy.html"
```

`$currentUrl` is the whole URL of the page, without any query params.
`baseUrl` is just that - the base URL of the website.
`$currentSlug` should be the former without the latter (`books/our-series/boffin-boy.html`), but the `str_replace` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

`.lcl` is just a domain ending I am using for my local dev environment.

I hope I'm just missing something obvious. Any help please?

EDIT: As highlighted in answers below, `string(27)` is more than it should be. This is how I am now trying to get `$baseUrl`:

```
$baseUrl = Mage::getUrl(); // this is a core Magento function
$baseUrl = trim($baseUrl);
$baseUrl = str_replace("\0", "", $baseUrl);
$baseUrl = (string) $baseUrl;

var_dump(addslashes($baseUrl));

// outputs the same length, string(27)
```

Someone looks to have had the same problem here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100579/why-doesnt-this-url-comparison-work

Even though it's a Magento function, there should still be a pure PHP to get the characters out of that variable that I need, shouldn't there?

Comment: What happens if you take a smaler part and replace out? Say, only "mysite". Maybe there is a char that it does not like?

Comment: str_replace is working fine showing only slug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `var_dump()` output of `$baseUrl` it says the string lenght is 27, but shows only 18 characters. There must be hidden characters in string, thats why function cant find it in `$currentUrl`.

Try to check whats inside with `var_dump(addslashes($baseUrl));` and remove hidden characters. Then it should work. A question remains, how is the variable being created. I bet `\0` bytes are added somehow.

To remove `\0` bytes if string contains them:

```
str_replace("\0", "", $baseUrl);
```

And then your replacing should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I've tried your suggestions (edited my answer); still have the length output as 27. Very strange!

Comment: Show output right after `$baseUrl = Mage::getUrl();` with `var_dump(addslashes($baseUrl));`

Comment: Try to output the string with `echo json_encode($baseUrl);` does it still shows same?

Comment: Yes. I just used this hexdump function ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432810/php-html-display-hidden-characters ) and only there could I see ?___SID=U at the end of the string. Looks like it's a Magento thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300200/magento-sid-u-appearing-in-some-urls I've changed the Magento function I am using and the issue is solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why the second line contains 27 chars?

```
string(27) "http://mysite.lcl/"
```

This code works for me :

```
<?php
$currentUrl = 'http://mysite.lcl/books/our-series/boffin-boy.html';
$baseUrl = 'http://mysite.lcl/';

var_dump($currentUrl);
var_dump($baseUrl);
// strip out base url, so we just get slug of page
$currentSlug = str_replace($baseUrl,'',$currentUrl);
var_dump($currentSlug);
```

Comment: You're right, thanks for highlighting that, I didn't notice it. If I do the same thing I am getting the expected result. It must be how I am getting the `$baseUrl`, but I don't understand how when I `var_dump` it says it is a string with more than the visible characters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) ?

```
$url='http://mysite.lcl/books/our-series/boffin-boy.html';

var_dump(preg_replace("/(http|https):\/\/((?:[a-z][a-z\.\d\-]+)\.(?:[a-z][a-z\-]+))(?![\w\.])/is", '', $url));
```

Output:

```
string(33) "/books/our-series/boffin-boy.html"
```

Comment: That works as an alternative solution, however it doesn't solve the mystery of why `str_replace` is not working.